# How do I show constructor comments within javadocs?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a class with a constructor with getters and setters and need to create a javadoc for them all.

The getters and setters both have their comments when I made the javadoc but for some reason, the constructor isn't appearing within the javadoc. Note: I am creating the javadocs within CMD. I have tried changing HTML versions but have still come up with nothing

here is what the class looks like:

```
/**
 * PersonalDetails class
 *
 * <p>Details the general information of a person involved in Saint Louis 
 University
 */

public class PersonalDetails {
    private String name;

/**
 * Creates a person with the specified characteristics
 * @param name a String containing the name of the person
 * @param sy   a String specifying the current school year
 * @param idNo a String containing the id number of the person
 */
PersonalDetails(String name, String sy, String idNo){
    this.name = name;
    this.sy = sy;
    this.idNo = idNo;
}

/**
 * Registers the name of the person
 * @param name a String containing the name of the person
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Retrieves the name of the person
 * @return a String representing the name of the person
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

}
```

I need to have the block comment for the constructor PersonalDetails to appear within the javadoc.

Comment: By default, `javadoc` only generates documentation for public and protected members. Your constructor is package-private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoke javadoc with the [`-package` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#GUID-3051737B-FFF9-45F9-85D1-5F07D6703592__GUID-430EA452-C842-47A2-AD4D-9E714F3C24E4) so it includes package-private API members.

> `-package`
>   Shows only package, protected, and public classes and members.

Answer (score 4):

Make it either public

```
public PersonalDetails(String name, String sy, String idNo){
```

or configure Javadoc that is also document your package visible constructor.